Intermediate scaling of $\int_{1/L}^{1} \dfrac{1-e^{-q^3t\sqrt{-\log(q)}}}{q}dq$
I'm trying to obtain the intermediate scaling of: $$f(L, t)=\int_{1/L}^{1} \dfrac{1-e^{-q^3t\sqrt{-\log(q)}}}{q}dq$$
when $L\to \infty$. From Mathematica, It seems that $f(L, t)$ at large $L$ increases logarithmically with $t$ and then reaches a plateau at $\log(L)$:

The later is analytically given by simply setting $t\to \infty$ before $L\to\infty$ but I'd like to obtain the intermediate logaritmic increase in $\log(t)$ analytically.

A simpler problem can be solved:
$$g(L, t)=\int_{1/L}^{1} \dfrac{1-e^{-q^3t}}{q}dq=\dfrac{\text{Ei}(-t/L^3)-\text{Ei}(-t)+3\log(L)}{3}$$
An asymptotic serie of $g$ around $L=\infty$ gives an increase of $\log(t)$. But it seems that the same kind of thing cannot be done for $f$.

$f(L,t)$ is defined at $L=\infty$, as the integral $,\int_0^1 \dfrac{1-e^{-q^3t\sqrt{-\log(q)}}}qdq,$ exists. Do you want to find the asymptotic of $f(L=\infty,t)$ at $t\gg1$?

@Svyatoslav yes!

We want to find the asymptotic of the integral
$$I(t)=\int_0^1\frac{1-e^{-q^3t\sqrt{-\ln q}}}qdq, \,\,t\to\infty$$
$$I(t)\overset{q^3=s}{=}\frac13\int_0^1\frac{1-e^{-st\sqrt{-\frac13\ln s}}}sds\overset{IBP}{=}\frac t{3\sqrt3}\int_0^1\left(-\frac12\sqrt{-\ln s}+(-\ln s)^\frac32\right)e^{-\frac{ts}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{-\ln s}}ds$$
$$\overset{x=\frac1s}{=}\frac t{3\sqrt3}\int_1^\infty\left(-\frac12\sqrt{\ln x}+(\ln x)^\frac32\right)e^{-\frac t{x\sqrt3}\sqrt{\ln x}}\,\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
$$=\frac t{3\sqrt3}\int_1^t\left(-\frac12\sqrt{\ln x}+(\ln x)^\frac32\right)e^{-\frac t{x\sqrt3}\sqrt{\ln x}}\,\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
$$+\frac t{3\sqrt3}\int_t^\infty\left(-\frac12\sqrt{\ln x}+(\ln x)^\frac32\right)e^{-\frac t{x\sqrt3}\sqrt{\ln x}}\,\frac{dx}{x^2}=I_1+I_2$$
We can estimate $I_1$ and show that non-vanishing at $t\to\infty$ contribution comes only from $I_2$. Making the substitution $x=ts$
$$I_2=\frac1{3\sqrt3}\int_1^\infty\left(-\frac12\sqrt{\ln(st)}+\big(\ln(st)\big)^\frac32\right)e^{-\frac{\sqrt{\ln(st)}}{\sqrt3 s}}\frac{ds}{s^2}$$
$$\overset{s=\frac1x}{=}\frac1{3\sqrt3}\int_0^1\left(-\frac12\sqrt{\ln t-\ln x}+\big(\ln t-\ln x\big)^\frac32\right)e^{-\frac{x\sqrt{\ln t}}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{1-\frac{\ln x}{\ln t}}}dx$$
$$\overset{s=\frac{\sqrt \ln t}{\sqrt 3}x}{=}\frac1{3\sqrt{\ln t}}\times$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{\ln t}}{\sqrt3}}\left(-\frac12\sqrt{\ln t}\sqrt{1-\frac{\ln\frac{\sqrt3 s}{\sqrt\ln t}}{\ln t}}+(\sqrt{\ln t})^3\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{\ln\frac{\sqrt3 s}{\sqrt\ln t}}{\ln t}}\right)^3\right)e^{-s\sqrt{1-\frac{\ln\frac{\sqrt3 s}{\sqrt{\ln t}}}{\ln t}}}ds$$
Decomposing the integrand in the powers of $\displaystyle \frac{\ln\frac{\sqrt3 s}{\sqrt{\ln t}}}{\ln t}$, expanding integration to $\infty$, integrating term by term and keeping only non-vanishing at $t\to\infty$ contribution,
$$I(t)\sim\frac1{3\sqrt{\ln t}}\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\left(-\frac12\sqrt{\ln t}+\big(\ln t\big)^\frac32-\frac32\sqrt{\ln t}\ln\frac{\sqrt 3 s}{\sqrt{\ln t}}-\frac s2\sqrt{\ln t}\ln\frac{\sqrt 3 s}{\sqrt{\ln t}}\right)ds$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(t)\sim\frac13\left(\ln t+\frac12\ln(\ln t)-\frac{\ln 3}2+\gamma\right)\,\,}$$
what provides a reasonable agreement with numeric check (WA) already at $t\sim 100$ (here and here)

What is unexpected -  the formula works already at $t\geqslant3$ :) - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%281-e%5E%7B-3x%5E3%5Csqrt%7B-%5Cln+x%7D%7D%29%2Fxdx and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F3%28%5Cln%283%29%2B1%2F2%5Cln%28%5Cln%283%29%29-1%2F2%5Cln3%2B%5Cgamma%29

One more superb asymptotics !

@Claude Leibovici, merci! Je pense que nous sommes également passionnés par la beauté et l’élégance, et quoi de plus élégant que les mathématiques ? :)

Je suis toujours emerveillé par vos solutions. Elles sont belles, élégantes, simples (après les avoir lues !!). Amitiés. By the way, where did you work in France ? (just curious). Cheers :-)

@Claude Leibovici, merci encore! I studied in a specialised French school in SU, worked for Moulinex and Saint-Gobain (mostly, in sales), and got one-year full-time MBA in EDHEC (Nice). Tous les chemins mènent à Paris/Nice ))) Merry Christmas!
